# Distinguishing different processes spawned by multiprocessing

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have an application that uses `multiprocessing`.  It creates several processes using `multiprocessing.Process(name='foo', target=fn)`.  I would like to be able to see which of the processes is consuming more resources (CPU, memory) through the task manager, but all these processes end up being named `python.exe`.

Is there a way to distinguish between the spawned processes?  I'm running under Windows.

Comment: They have unique PID's.  (`os.getpid()`)  What more do you need to know?

Comment: Thank you.  It took me a while to realize you can show the PID in task manager (view/select columns).  It's been a long day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each process has different pid, you can get it with http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.getpid

I'm just not sure if there is pid visible in task manager though :<

Comment: The PID is visible in the task manager.  You can enable it through the view menu (select columns item).